# Как сделать из датафрейма несколько таблиц?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм :

```
        1125       1003       1008       1016      1007      1009      1019  
0  37.379310  20.689655   9.517241   5.586207  7.379310  4.000000  6.137931  
1  29.225352  18.265845  12.500000   7.174296  7.174296  8.186620  6.602113  
2  24.212344  34.484247   9.365559   6.085455  5.092792  7.293915  5.135952  
3  32.806859  27.481949   7.445848   6.498195  7.310469  6.001805  4.602888  
4  32.542373  13.220339  10.411622  13.414044  6.634383  5.520581  7.312349
```

Как из него сделать 7 датафреймов по одной колонке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать словарь с ключами - именами столбцов:

```
In [13]: dct = {col:df[col] for col in df.columns}

In [14]: dct.keys()
Out[14]: dict_keys(['1125', '1003', '1008', '1016', '1007', '1009', '1019'])

In [15]: dct['1125']
Out[15]:
0    37.379310
1    29.225352
2    24.212344
3    32.806859
4    32.542373
Name: 1125, dtype: float64

In [16]: dct['1019']
Out[16]:
0    6.137931
1    6.602113
2    5.135952
3    4.602888
4    7.312349
Name: 1019, dtype: float64
```

или список:

```
In [19]: lst = [df[[col]] for col in df.columns]

In [20]: lst[0]
Out[20]:
        1125
0  37.379310
1  29.225352
2  24.212344
3  32.806859
4  32.542373

In [21]: lst[1]
Out[21]:
        1003
0  20.689655
1  18.265845
2  34.484247
3  27.481949
4  13.220339

In [22]: lst[6]
Out[22]:
       1019
0  6.137931
1  6.602113
2  5.135952
3  4.602888
4  7.312349
```